# Getting sscreenshot attached for failed test to allure report in format: datetime-classsname-testname selenium, testng, allure

Tags: selenium, testng, allure

I am using testng, maven, allure in my framework. Currently my screenshots for failed test are saved in surefire-reports/screenshots as :
datetime-classname-methodname
eg: 09-22-2017_01.13.23_ClassName_Methodname.png

Here is code for this :

```
 @AfterMethod
    protected void screenShotIfFail(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            takeScreenShot(result.getMethod());
        }
    }

private void takeScreenShot(String name) throws IOException {
        String path = getRelativePath(name);
        File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, new File(path));
        String filename = makeScreenShotFileName(name);
        System.out.println("Taking Screenshot! " + filename);
        Reporter.log("<a href=" + path + " target='_blank' >" + filename
                + "</a>");
           }
 private void takeScreenShot(ITestNGMethod testMethod) throws IOException {
        String nameScreenShot = testMethod.getTestClass().getRealClass()
                .getSimpleName()
                + "_" + testMethod.getMethodName();
        takeScreenShot(nameScreenShot);
    }
private String makeScreenShotFileName(String name) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_hh.mm.ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date) + "_" + name + ".png";
    }
private String getRelativePath(String name) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(".", "target", "surefire-reports", "screenShots",
                makeScreenShotFileName(name));
        File directory = new File(path.toString());
        return directory.getCanonicalPath();
    }
```

For getting attached to allure reports, i tried @Attachment like this :

```
@Attachment(value = "filename", type = "image/png")
    private byte[] takeScreenShot(String name) throws IOException {
                return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
```

Screenshot is getting attached to allure report, but how can i get it in same format as in surefire reports.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom name directly into method annotated with `@Attachment`:

```
@Attachment(value = "{name}", type = "image/png")
private byte[] takeScreenShot(String name) throws IOException {
    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}
```

The only difference between Allure 1 and Allure 2 is in `value` parameter. For Allure 1 use the following syntax:

```
value = "{0}"
```

Where `{0}` is reference to the first method's parameter (its index).

For Allure 2, use the following:

```
value = "{name}"
```

In this case `{name}` is the name of a method's parameter.